# Why am I getting [Error] expected primary-expression before ' ' c++?

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error

I am not sure why i am getting these errors in my code. I am trying to make a basic skeleton idea for a robot and it needs to pass through the commands in main() which were provided to me. I've attempted to look up errors similar to this with no luck. I think it's something related to how I use the methods in main but I'm not sure how I would change it. Help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
enum direction {North, South, East, West};
class ur_Robot
{
    private:
        int ave;
        int str;
        direction dir;
        int num_beeper;
        bool on;
    public:
        ur_Robot(int a, int str, direction d, int nBeeper);
        print(const ur_Robot & u) const;
        void pickBeeper(int nBeeper);
        void turnLeft(enum direction);
        void move(enum direction, int b);
        void putBeeper(int nBeeper);
        void turnOff(bool o);
};

ur_Robot::ur_Robot(int a, int str, direction d, int nBeeper)
{
    ave = a;
    str = str;
    dir = d;
    num_beeper = nBeeper;
    on = 1;


}

ur_Robot::print(const ur_Robot & u) const
{
    if(on == 1)
    {
        cout << ave << " avenue, " << str; 
        cout << " street, " << dir << ", "; 
        cout << num_beeper << " number of beepers " << endl;
    };
    if(on == 0)
        cout << "ur_Robot is off and unable to take commands.";
}
void ur_Robot::turnLeft(enum direction)
{
    if(on == 1)
    {
        if (dir == North)
            dir = West; 
        if (dir == South)
            dir = East;
        if (dir ==  West)
            dir = South;
        if (dir == East)
            dir = North;
    }
    if(on == 0)
        cout << "ur_Robot is off and unable to take commands.";
}

void ur_Robot::putBeeper(int nBeeper)
{
    if(on == 1)
        num_beeper =- num_beeper;
    if(on == 0)
        cout << "ur_Robot is off and unable to take commands.";
}

void ur_Robot::pickBeeper(int nBeeper)
{
    if(on == 1)
        num_beeper =+ num_beeper;
    if(on == 0)
        cout << "ur_Robot is off and unable to take commands.";
}

void ur_Robot::turnOff(bool o)
{
    on = 0; 
}

int main()
{
  ur_Robot karel(1,1,East,10);

  karel.print (const ur_Robot & u) const;

  karel.move(enum direction, int b);
  karel.pickBeeper(int nBeeper);
  karel.move(enum direction, int b);
  karel.print(const ur_Robot & u) const;

  karel.turnLeft(enum direction);
  karel.move(enum direction, int b);
  karel.putBeeper(int nBeeper);
  karel.putBeeper(int nBeeper);
  karel.turnOff(bool o);

  karel.print(const ur_Robot & u);

  return 0;
}

In function 'int main()':
88  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'const'
90  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'enum'
90  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
91  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
92  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'enum'
92  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
93  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'const'
95  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'enum'
96  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'enum'
96  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
97  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
98  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'
99  [Error] expected primary-expression before 'bool'
101 [Error] expected primary-expression before 'const'
```

Comment: Those are function definitions you have in main, not function calls. rather than `karel.print (const ur_Robot & u) const;`, you want something more like `karel.print (somethingOfType_ur_Robot);`

Comment: Looking back at that, You probably don't need to pass anything into `karel.print`. It is a `ur_Robot`, so you can use its `this` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Small Stuff:

As said above, first clean up your declaration of

```
print(const ur_Robot & u) const;
```

To

```
void print(const ur_Robot & u) const;
```

Likewise, you need to change the definition of

```
ur_Robot::print(const ur_Robot & u) const
{
    //...
}
```

To

```
void ur_Robot::print(const ur_Robot & u) const
{
    //...
}
```

Additionally, your use of `using std::cout` and `using std::cin` is somewhat non-standard, and is covered by the much broader

```
using namespace std;
```

### The real issue:

Most of the issue within your code is due to the fact that you aren't passing anything into `ur_Robot`'s member functions as you call them, and irrespective of that, *you don't need to*.

Your implementation of `print(const ur_Robot & u) const`, for example, only uses member variables, so you can cut out the reference to another `ur_Robot` object entirely:

```
void print() const;
```

Similarly, it's definition should be shortened as well:

```
void ur_Robot::print() const
{
    //...
}
```

This goes for nearly all of `ur_Robot`'s member functions.

Additionally, `void ur_Robot::move(enum direction, int b)` is never properly defined, so attempting to use it in `main()` will have less than desirable results.

Comment: On the `using std::cout`, that's very standard and it's preferred over a whopping `using namespace std`. Better to selectively import what you need than to dump the entire namespace into global.

Comment: I'd normally agree, but in the case of the OP's code, I think it's much better to be overly broad than too specific, as performance/memory-management aren't really concerns here at the moment. However, I may have been overly ambiguous regarding my reference to 'non-standard' :) So, you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a return type in the declaration of the member function:

```
print(const ur_Robot & u) const;
```

Looking at the implementation, you need to use:

```
void print(const ur_Robot & u) const;
```

Once you fix the declaration, the implementation needs to be modified to match the declaration.